# Iptables dropping HTTP 302 packages contain suspicious domain string

Tags: iptables, tcp, http

The HTTP 302 packages I want to block have:

```
Header

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.yxjiaodai.com/ad/?id=1023&url=http%3A//a1819.oadz.com/link/C/1819/3081547/dtMdon4l79FwsIo2JXEHqtdp5eQ_/p007/0/http%3A//www.womai.com/AdvRedirect.do%3Furi%3Dhttp%3A//www.womai.com/%26utm_source%3DtongyongG%26utm_medium%3Dtongyong%26utm_campaign%3Damg
Connection: close
```

I want to drop all these packages by matching "yxjiaodai.com", is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use deep packet inspection for this task, which iptables is not really made for this.

You could start with string matching like this

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d DESTINATIONIP -m string --algo bm --string "HTTP/1.1 302 Found" -j DROP
```

Replace `DESTINATIONIP` with the IP address of your machine.

But bear in mind that this is naturally a task for an intrusion detection system.

Comment: I don't have a webserver, can I just use `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string 'yxjiaodai.com' -j DROP`?

Comment: Yes, this should work.

Comment: I tried it on my router but didn't work, tried also FORWARD chain, NAT table, none worked, did I miss something simple?

Comment: How can I limit it to a specific Location? Like "http://172.16.0.5/*".