# Iptables dropping HTTP 302 packages of specific Location string

Tags: iptables

The HTTP 302 packages I want to block have:

```
Header

HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://172.16.0.5/[***]
Content-Type: text/html;
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

I want to drop all these packages by matching "http://172.16.0.5/" on my OpenWRT router.

Now I am using `-m string --algo bm --string "HTTP/1.1 302 "` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229967/38666 to block all 302 package, how can I limit it to "http://172.16.0.5/" only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If packets coming from 172.16.0.5 you can use

```
-m string --algo bm --string "HTTP/1.1 302 " --source 172.16.0.5
```

otherwise use string matching again

```
-m string --algo bm --string "HTTP/1.1 302 " -m string --algo bm --string "172.16.0.5"
```

Also I suggest you to use "--algo kmp" instead of "bm" since I experienced bm algorithm might miss some packages.

And don't forget that string matching rules is costly if you also need some performance.

Comment: Yes. `bm` does miss packages during my test.